# specific SPARQL query with jena

Tags: sparql, jena

I use apache-jena 2.10.2 command-line tools and try to insert some data in my graph:

```
tdbupdate --loc /Users/graph  "INSERT DATA { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Mais>   <http://ch.ingredientmatching.graph/eaternitySynonym> 15 }"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't add anything. If I change something in the predicate, e.g. delete or change a character, then it works. 
The following works:

```
tdbupdate --loc /Users/graph  "INSERT DATA { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Mais>   <http://ch.ingredientmatching.graph/eaternitySynonyn> 15 }"
```

Where I changed the last character: eaternitySynonym in eaternitySynonyn. To see if it worked, I do:

```
tdbquery --loc /Users/graph  "SELECT * WHERE { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Mais> ?p ?o }"
```

and look if it's in the output.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What are the outputs you're getting when you run the query?

Comment: Also, how have you set up 2.10.2?  It's not available in the [distributions](http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/) yet.  This might be a better question to send to the [Jena mailing list](http://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/index.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually solved it, I found 2.10.2 when I googled for the corresponding maven repository. I now use 2.10.1 and it just works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the problem you describe, but I cannot.  The following console transcript shows the creation of an empty data file, the creation of a TDB store for it, the execution of the update that you said didn't work, and the execution of a query asking for all triples, which returns the triple that was inserted.

```
$ tdbloader2 --loc graph data.n3 
 11:05:38 -- TDB Bulk Loader Start
 11:05:38 Data phase
INFO  Load: data.n3 -- 2013/08/28 11:05:43 EDT
INFO  Total: 0 tuples : 0.12 seconds : 0.00 tuples/sec [2013/08/28 11:05:43 EDT]
 11:05:43 Index phase
 11:05:43 Index phase end
 11:05:43 -- TDB Bulk Loader Finish
 11:05:43 -- 5 seconds
$ tdbupdate --loc graph "INSERT DATA { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Mais>   <http://ch.ingredientmatching.graph/eaternitySynonym> 15 }"
$ tdbquery --loc graph  "SELECT * WHERE { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Mais> ?p ?o }"
--------------------------------------------------------------
| p                                                     | o  |
==============================================================
| <http://ch.ingredientmatching.graph/eaternitySynonym> | 15 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Unless there's something else in your setup that you're not describing, it seems like this should work.  The above was executed with the following versions of Jena, ARQ, and TDB:

```
$ tdbquery --version
Jena:       VERSION: 2.10.1
Jena:       BUILD_DATE: 2013-05-11T22:05:51+0100
ARQ:        VERSION: 2.10.1
ARQ:        BUILD_DATE: 2013-05-11T22:05:51+0100
RIOT:       VERSION: 2.10.1
RIOT:       BUILD_DATE: 2013-05-11T22:05:51+0100
TDB:        VERSION: 0.10.1
TDB:        BUILD_DATE: 2013-05-11T22:05:51+0100
```